# How to write to an Excel File in 64 bit R

Tags: excel, r, 64-bit

I'm creating a TermDocumentMatrix from a corpus in **64 bit R** (the 32 bit R crashes because of the size of the corpus). I need to **save** that TermDocumentMatrix ***in an excel file in a matrix format***. When I'm working in 32 bit R with small corpus and the TermDocumentMatrix is generated, I can convert it to a matrix and save it using write.xls . But, it seems we **can't use write.xls in 64 bit** R. ***So, is there an alternative to saving a matrix in an excel file in 64 bit R ???***

Thnx in advance. Hope my very first question @Stackoverflow gets answered .

Comment: Save it as .csv instead. Excel will read that.

Comment: A bit **less** use of **bold** font would actually make your question **easier** to read.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `write.csv` function.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the best solutions is mirai solution's package XLConnect. It works under all Windows version I tested, has the largest set of functions I know of, and is very fast.

Comment: Added three years later: Still ok, but the "is very fast" is not correct. It can be very slow for large workbooks.